# Pro Tempore election for 2021

Tags: discussion, election

Last week we opened nominations for [a special election](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/election) two Pro Tempore Moderator positions for Computer Graphics. We're extending nominations by another week to allow more time for people to come forward and self-nominate.

For full details on the process, see the [announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Users can [nominate themselves](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/election) **through April, 26**. Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the `discussion` and `election`tags.)
- On April 26, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-moderator-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-pa), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election I'll announce the results on meta on May 4.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.